# Add file to SVN (VisualSVN) with the same name

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

I did an "update to revision" (from 49 to 46). I created a new file with the same name than a file available in the revision version, when I try to add it. I get this error : "already exist". I tried a "clean up" no success.

Any idea ?

Thanks,

Comment: You are trying to go rev 46 to add a file that also exists in rev 49? That isn't possible. But why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using "update to revision" to an earlier revision is not the right way to undo your changes!
Use one of the [many right ways to do this](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-howto-rollback.html).

Then you can add your file without an error.